# Time between ssh_channel_write and read is abnormaly long?

Tags: c++, c, ssh, openssh

I'm setting up and client/server application in c++ with the libraby openssh (they are on the same host)

When I try to send data from the server to the client I use the function ssh_channel_write (and ssh_channel_read to get the data)

My code looks like this :

```
std::string msg = "hello";
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
ssh_channel_write(chan, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
```

And for the client :

```
char buffer[256];
int nbytes;
nbytes = ssh_channel_read(chan, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
```

It takes about 40ms before the data is read. It's too long for my application (I'm sending a lot of messages).

Does someone as ever encountered this problem?

How could I fix it?

Comment: Well if the server and client aren't on the same host there's always going to be network latency. I wouldn't say 40 ms is abnormally long.

Comment: Oups, forgot to mention it. They are on the same host

Comment: If you won't be able to speed up performance, consider using nonblocking SSH channel operations to be able to do some other processing while transfering your data.

Comment: If they're on the same host why are you using encryption?

Comment: @user207421 The same host is just for testing, they are supposed to be on different hosts in production.